# PhpStorm include expression is not resolved

Tags: php, phpstorm

I use PhpStorm to open an existing project.

This project runs perfectly and the server gives no errors and warnings. But in PhpStorm it gives a warning.

There is a declaration of a static variable in `static.php`

```
static  $OJ_LANG="en";
```

And in `foo.php`

```
require_once "./static.php";
require_once "./lang/$OJ_LANG.php";
```

in PhpStorm, he tells me the path not found because the include expression is not resolved, but he can tell what the path exactly is:

```
Path 'lang/en.php' not found
Include expression is not resolved.
```

So why the expression is not resolved? I use static, and he can even tell what the path exactly is: `Path 'lang/en.php' not found`

And the `en.php` certainly exists, when I use `require_once "./lang/en.php";`, it is happy.

[image: see screenshot here]

Comment: Why are you using `static`? You don't seem to be inside a function or class so it does nothing. And you should post the complete php error message.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. the code is written in a project by others.  I think he meant to do something like define or const. But the warning still exists when I replace it with `define("OJ_LANG","en")` and `require_once "./lang".OJ_LANG.".php"`. And the code can run correctly, there are no errors, it is only the warning that phpStorm gives.

Comment: If you harcdode en.php (e.g. `require_once "./lang/en.php";`) -- will it find it? In my opinion -- just disable such inspections -- they add little value due to the very dynamic nature how include/require search works (e.g. PHP itself when including such files may look in multiple different folders while PhpStorm performs only static analysis with rather limited scope/options for possible paths).

Comment: Yes,` require_once "./lang/en.php";` does work. And how to disable this inspection? I can't find such options. Besides, warnings have its reasons, does it mean that such code style is not recommended? If so, how should I reconstruct it?